# How to handle Windows shell icons in JFace LabelProviders?

Tags: java, swt, jface, windows-shell

I would like to display files and folders in a `TreeViewer` with the associated Windows shell icons. I use the [`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931527.aspx) function to get the icons, and then I convert them to `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image`.

It works great, but when I display a large number of files I get an error: "org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles". SWT is right, I created too many images. Because I must return them from `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider.getImage(Object)`.

How should I handle this situation?

(I can't "cache" the images, because the icons can be dynamic, and even different for every folder.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to work out a way to identify the different unique images you get from `SHGetFileInfo` and only create one `Image` for each. You must also keep track of the images you create because you must also dispose of them.

You may be able to use `org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry` to help manage the images. This requires a string key to identify each image. It looks like `SHGetFileInfo` gives you an index number that could be used as a unique key.